# Select entries from a list that do not occur in the query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I use Postgres 9.1. I am running a query which is like

```
select count(distinct(user_id)) from users where user_id in (11,32,763,324,45,76,37,98,587);
```

Here the list of `user_id`s contains 600 entries. The result I am getting is 597. Thus there are 3 `user_id`s from the list, which are not present in the `users`. How do I get to know these 3 `user_id`s?

Please note that `user_id` is not the Primary Key of `users`

Comment: So `user_id` is the primary key of table `users`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, no it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` in your count-query only makes sense if `user_id` is not defined `UNIQUE`.
We don't need it either way for the query you ask for:

```
SELECT t.user_id
FROM   unnest('{11,32,763,324,45,76,37,98,587}'::int[]) t(user_id)
LEFT   JOIN users u USING (user_id)
WHERE  u.user_id IS NULL;
```

Beware of `NOT IN` if NULL values can be involved on either side of the expression! `IN` / `NOT IN` with a long value list also scales poorly.

Details:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91539/3684)
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)